# Prove that $n \in \mathbb{Z}^\star \Leftrightarrow n \mid 1$ and $n-1 \mid 1$ or $n+1 \mid 1$, and $(x-1)/(t-1) \equiv n \pmod {t-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, divisibility

I want to prove the following lemma:

> Let $F[t,t^{-1}]$ be the ring of the polynomials in $t$ and
>   $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$ and assume that the characteristic of $F$ is zero.
>
> Then for any $n$ in $F[t, t^{-1}]$, $n$ is a nonzero integer
>   if and only if
>
> - $n$ divides $1$
> - either $n-1$ divides $1$ or $n+1$
>     divides $1$, and
> - there is a power $x$ of $t$, so that $\dfrac{x-1}{t-1}
>    \equiv n \pmod {t-1}$.

Could you give me some hints how we could show that?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I thought that we could use the following, but I am not sure:

an integer is nonnegative iff it is the sum of four integer squares and $x$ is nonzero iff there is a nonnegative integer $y$ so that $x=y+1$ or $x=−y−1$.

Does this help?

Comment: before you ask for "some" hints;please show "some" of your thoughts

Comment: I thought that we could use the following, but I am not sure: 
an integer is nonnegative iff it is the sum of four integer squares and $x$ is nonzero iff there is a nonnegative integer $y$ so that $x=y+1$ or $x=-y-1$. Does this help? @learnmore

Comment: I would not use $n$ for a polynomial, it is very very confusing.

Comment: Also, $(x-1)\equiv n\pmod{t-1}$ is good enough. Don't use division to mean taking modulo.

Comment: Also, $R^{\times}$ is usually used for the group of units of a ring $R$. But you seem to want non-zero integers?

Comment: @MaryStar: add your thoughts to the question, not as comments. Comments are transient and not always looked at by those who might close as off-topic.

Comment: @MaryStar: it would be clearer if the statement were "$n$ is a non-zero integer if and only if **all of the following are true**"

Answer (score 1):

I had wanted to give some hints and then put the solution into the "hidden" mode.  However, the command `>!` didn't seem to be working with my text (this might have something to do with LaTeX commands), so I will just put my solution then.  I would greatly appreciate if anybody can suggest a way to hide my text below.

First, suppose $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.  Clearly, $n\mid 1$, and either $n+1\mid 1$ or $n-1\mid 1$.  Furthermore, if $n>0$, then $$\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,t^j=n+(t-1)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,\frac{t^j-1}{t-1}\right)=n+(t-1)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^j\,t^k\right)\equiv n\pmod{t-1}\,.$$
If $n<0$, then
$$\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}=-t^{n}\left(\frac{t^{-n}-1}{t-1}\right)\equiv -t^n(-n)\equiv nt^n\equiv n\pmod{t-1}\,.$$

Now assume that $f(t)\in F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$ is such that
(a) $f(t)\mid 1$,
(b) $f(t)+1\mid 1$ or $f(t)-1\mid 1$, and
(c) there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}\equiv f(t)\pmod{t-1}$.
We shall prove that $f(t)=n \neq 0$.  Condition (c) implies that $f(t)-n$ is divisible by $t-1$.  Hence, $$f(t)=n+(t-1)\,g(t)$$ for some $g(t)\in F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$.  Since $f(t)\mid 1$, $f(t)$ is a unit in $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$, whence $f(t)=at^k$ for some $a\in F\setminus\{0\}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  If $f(t)\pm 1 \mid 1$, then $f(t)\pm 1$ is also a unit.  That is, $at^k\pm 1$ is of the form $bt^l$, where $b\in F\setminus\{0\}$ and $l\in\mathbb{Z}$.  If $k\neq 0$, we note that $at^k\pm1$ has a nonzero root in the algebraic closure of $F$, but $bt^l$ does not.  Therefore, $k=0$.  Hence, $f(t)=a$ is a nonzero, constant polynomial.  Now, from $f(t)=n+(t-1)\,g(t)$, we have $0\neq a=f(1)=n$.  Ergo, $f(t)=n \neq 0$ as desired.

Comment: At the direction where we suppose that $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ you say "Clearly, $n\mid 1$, and either $n+1\mid 1$ or $n-1\mid 1$." Does this mean that we suppose this? Or does this mean that each integer is invertible?   $$$$ Could you explain to me why the following equations hold? $$\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,t^j=n+(t-1)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,\frac{t^j-1}{t-1}\right)$$

Comment: At my second question how did we get the "$n$" out of the sum?

Comment: Sorry, I've been sick.  Just noticed now that you placed a few questions.  For the first one, about $n+1\mid 1$ or $n-1\mid 1$.  That is not an assumption.  Note that $x\mid 1$ if and only if $x\in F\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: The second question comes from $t^j-1=(t-1)\left(\frac{t^j-1}{t-1}\right)$.  You subtract each $t^j$ by $1$ from $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.  That is why you get $n$ in the front.

Comment: Why does it stand that $x \mid 1$ if and only if $x \in F \setminus \{0\}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, that would be true if I was talking about $F[t]$.  Just realized that it's about $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$.  I ask you: what are units of $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$?  If $x \in F$, show that either $x-1$ or $x+1$ is a unit of $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$.

Comment: The units of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ are the polynomials of which the coefficients are units in $F$. Is this correct? What information does the fact that $x \in F$ give to us?

Comment: Units of $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$ are any element of the form $at^k$ with $a\in F\setminus\{0\}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  What happens if $x\in F$?  Does either $x-1$ or $x+1$ take this form?

Comment: Which identities do the elements of a field of characteristic $0$ have?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: You say that the units of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ are the polynomials of the form $at^k$ with $a \in F \setminus \{0\}$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. We want that $a \in F \setminus \{0\}$ beacuse every element different from zero has an inverse in a field, right? Does it play a role that the characteristic of $F$ is zero?

Comment: That the units of $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$ are nonzero monomials $at^k$ is true for a field $F$ of any characteristic.

Comment: I see... At one of your last camment you ask "What if $x \in F$ ? Does either $x-1$ or $x+1$ take this form?". I haven't really understood why $x-1$ or $x+1$ ould take this form... Could you explain it to me?

Comment: That would mean that if $x$ is invertible then either the next or the previous number is also invertible, right? But why?

Comment: Does this stand because of the following? Since $F$ is a field, each non-zero element $x$ is invertible. SInce $x$ is non-zero at least one of $x-1$ and $x+1$ is also non-zero, so at least one of them is invertible, i.e., either $x-1 \mid 1$ or $x+1 \mid 1$. Is this correct?